# OpenFileDialog.FileName to upload an image using vb.net to SQL Server 2008

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008, image-uploading

I have code for uploading a photo in vb.net to SQL Server. On `OpenFileDialog` I just need the `imageName`, but it's all with the location in my text field.

```
Dim bmap As Image
Dim data As IDataObject
Dim fd As OpenFileDialog = New OpenFileDialog()
    fd.Title = "Select your Image."
    fd.InitialDirectory = My.Settings.ImageDefect
    fd.Filter = "All Files|*.*|Bitmaps|*.bmp|GIFs|*.gif|JPEGs|*.jpg|PNGs|*.png"
    fd.RestoreDirectory = False
    If fd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
        PictureBox.ImageLocation = fd.FileName
        **TxtImageFile.Text = fd.FileName**
```

in my text field, I have `C:\Users\susi\Pictures\Capture.png`

How can I get `Capture.png` in my text field? Please somebody help me, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Use the static methods of the [Path Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  [(Path.GetFileName)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilename%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 TxtImageFile.Text = = Path.GetFileName(fd.FileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot, I get the ImageName with this code :

```
TxtImageFile.Text = fd.FileName
Dim names As String = TxtImageFile.Text.Trim
Dim phrase As String = names.Substring(names.LastIndexOf("\"c) + 1)
TxtImageFile.Text = phrase
```

thanks for the answer :)